# C - get CLEAN numeric variable from string

Tags: c, bash

I have been fiddling with some C programming for a little LCD project.

I have a string, which executed in `BASH`(script), gives back a value from 0 - 100 (Volume level)
the string is like this :

> !/bin/bash
>
> amixer get 'DIYINHK Clock Selector',0 | awk '/[/ {getline; print $5}' | tr -d '[]%'

I need this value returning, so that i can use it in a if/else statement e.g.
I think the value is returned in a ascii way or something ?

the printf output is right, eg. when `amixer` is 98, the printf onscreen is 98
but on lcd, there is a kind of _ after the 98.... like this : `98_`
its a "returning" value of some kind ?

What i need, is a clean number which i can use as eg. :

> if (get_volume <= 30)
>
> statement;
>
> else if (get_volume <=50 )
>
> statement;
>
> else if ....
>      .......

here is a snippet :

> FILE *fpipe;
>
> char *command = (char *)"/home/pi/lcd/get_volume.sh"; // get_volume script
>
> char line[256];
>
> ```
>    if (! (fpipe = (FILE*)popen(command,"r")) )
>            {
>                    perror("PROBLEMS");
>            exit(1);
>            }
>
>    while ( fgets( line, sizeof line, fpipe))
> ```
>
> lcdPosition(lcd, 0,0);
>
> lcdPrintf(lcd, line); // Print output on LCD
>
> printf("\nline = %s \n", line); // Print output on screen

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html
Look for 7.1.2.2. Numeric comparisons
Google does not bite you

Answer (score 0):

[`atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) function converts a string representing a number to an int. So to get a "clean number", you need something like:

```
int volume = atoi(line);
```